# find the determinant of matrix 2

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

if the determinant of A is given by $ \begin{vmatrix}
        a & c \\
        b & d \\
\end{vmatrix}=5$

find\begin{vmatrix}
        2a & 3d \\
        2b & 3c \\
\end{vmatrix}

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What have you done so far and where did you get stuck? Tell us these so that we can help you better.

Comment: the problem i have faced is that c and d are replaced  i tried to take 6 out of the det but did not know what to do with c and d

Comment: There is no a general form to compute the determinant because it depends on the entries. For example, take the matrices $ \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 \\
        0 & 5 \\
\end{bmatrix}$ and $ \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 4 \\
        -1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$. Both have determinant $5$, but $\begin{vmatrix}
        2a & 3d \\
        2b & 3c \\
\end{vmatrix}$ are different.

Comment: Those both have det $30$.

Comment: @Zestylemonzi, No. For the first matrix, det  becomes $0$.

Comment: Oops sorry, hadn't noticed $d$ and $c$ swapped - I think that's probably a typo by the OP.

Comment: @Zestylemonzi, this is not a typo. See his comment.

Comment: Apologies, I'll delete my comment since it's taking up so much space!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have
$$
\det\begin{bmatrix}
2a & 3d \\
2b & 3c
\end{bmatrix}=
6\det\begin{bmatrix}
a & d \\
b & c
\end{bmatrix}
$$
so the problem is whether we can deduce the last determinant from
$$
\det\begin{bmatrix}
a & c \\
b & d
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The answer is no.

You can't even predict whether the first matrix is invertible or not, given that the second matrix is invertible. Just consider the case $a=1$, $b=0$, $c=0$ and $d=5$.

I claim that we can suitably choose $a,b,c,d$ so that
$$
\det\begin{bmatrix} a & d \\ b & c \end{bmatrix}=k
$$
where $k$ is arbitrary. The equations are
$$
\begin{cases}
ad-bc=5 \\[4px]
ac-bd=k
\end{cases}
$$
Multiply the first equation by $d$ and the second one by $c$ and subtract: we get
$$
ad^2-ac^2=5d-kc
$$
that is
$$
a=\frac{5d-kc}{c^2-d^2}
$$
so, as long as $c\ne d$ (which would make the problem trivial) and $c\ne -d$, we have the thesis.

If $d=-c\ne0$, one matrix is obtained from the other by multiplying the second column by $-1$, so the determinant changes sign.